# Django rest framework - Serialize all fields of native object

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to serialize an object that's a mix of normal fields, model objects and querysets. I want to include all normal fields and then I'll create serializers for each model type. The problem is I can't automatically add all the non-model fields from my class:

```
class ObjectSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
  class Meta:
    fields = '__all__'
```

It Gives me an empty object. Is there any way to include all fields using non-model serializer? Or is there better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

`__all__` only works with `ModelSerializer`. For non-model seriaizers you have to specify a `tuple` or a `list` object with field names.